# (Eclipse) Hangs when building project: copying resources to output folder

Tags: eclipse, build, freeze

This has been happening intermittently, but now its consistent.

When I go to build the project, eclipse just hangs forever at this step:

copying resources to output folder

I saw a suggestion to remove all non-java resources from the project and put them back in one at a time, but that is impractical for the size of this project.

Comment: Do you have a really large file (like a binary resource in a package) in a source folder somewhere? If so, exclude the massive file and Eclipse should function normally. I've had this happen to me before w/ massive DBUnit XML's.

Comment: That's a good thought.  What's strange is nothing really changed in the project, other than normal incremental development.  I downloaded the latest Helios, and rebuilt from CVS.  Just using a new Eclipse and the old workspace didn't solve the problem.  Guess I'll chalk this one up to the IDE instance only lasts for so long under heavy usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a new workspace.  A new eclipse instance didn't fix it.  A new workspace and the old eclipse worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by using the following steps:

1) Closing eclipse - In case it does not close - Kill the process
2) Manually delete everything in the output folder
3) Start eclipse with -clean option -> eclipse.exe -clean

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, but now I've solved it.

The cause was not one really large file, but a lot of small files adding up to a large total.

For me it was not a problem to move these files, since in hindsight they didn't really belong there anyway.

Comment: I had the same problem. I just waited some minutes and it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

i just had the same problem, my problem was that i added an wrong/to large folder with sources and added it for the source-lookup. so eclipse tried to go through hundreds of jar-files on each build.

removing the wrong parent-folder from source-lookup-path fixed my problem.