# Why does my Eclipse takes so much times to clean files?

Tags: eclipse, windows

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 and recently it became more and more frequent that it takes lots of time when it has to delete files. For example in these contexts:

- mvn clean launched from Eclipse
- cleaning output folder in case of automatic projects build by Eclipse
- deploying a war on a server (deletion of the previous deployment)

I've checked this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686364/eclipse-hangs-when-building-project-copying-resources-to-output-folder) but working in a fresh new workspace has no effect.

I may have a clue: to gain some time I 'help' Eclipse by deleting the files myself with Windows Explorer. Windows often launches a pop-up saying that I need admin right to do that. I just hit Enter (I am admin user) and the files are quickly deleted. If Eclipse had no right to delete the files I would have expected an error, instead it just takes much more time to actually delete the files.

Why could be the cause of that? Knowing that the clue may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: no solution has been found to the problem. I got a new desktop with a fresh Win7 image and I don't have the problem, working with the same Eclipse projects.
This would indicate that the problem came from a misconfiguration of the Windows user permission. Sadly, no more details available.